# Want to parse javascript variable to mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, json

I have a js file and js variable named myData in array. I want to store all component of myData into mysql dbase. I tried using ajax (first of all, parse it into json file), but still fail. I'm new in json and ajax. It's my javascript. is it wrong?

```
        var myData = [];
        var arrayOfMarker = [];

        function myFunctions(maps) {
            var count = 1;

            var arr = new Array();
            for(var i=0;i<myData.length;i++){
                var typef = '';
                if (document.getElementById('optionsRadios1').checked == true) {
                    typef = 'Building';
                } else {
                    typef = 'House';
                }
                var ob = {0 : count, 1 : myData[i][1], 2 : myData[i][2], 3 : typef};
                arr.push(ob);
                count += 1;
            }
            var myJString = JSON.stringify(arr);
            console.log(myJString);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'inputdata.php',
                type:"POST",
                dataType:'json',
                data: {data: myJString},
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(request, status, error){}
            });

        }
    </script>
```

And it is my php file: inputdata.php

```
<?php
        $con = mysql_connect("root","","")or die('Could not connect:   '.mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("fpgis",$con);
        $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO     pointproperty(noPoint,latPoint,lngPoint,tipePoint)VALUES('$data[0]','$data[1]','            $data[2]','$data[3]')";
        if(!mysql_query($sql,$con)){
             die('Error : '.mysql_error()); 
        }
  ?>
```

Please tell me how solve this problem. I really need solution. Your solution is helpful for me. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Are you forget about you have array of objects `[{}, {}, ...]`? You should iterate it in php.

Comment: how about my ajax code? is it true?

Comment: it's not true :) But looks like correct) You can to bypass `JSON.stringify`/`json_decode($_POST['data'], true)` part.. Just send it as js array/object, and php will receive ready array. Debug it with `print_r()` first.

Comment: You could just save it as a huge text string in your mysql, and JSON.stringify it at javascript level, i suppose

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use mysql_ in the first place, use mysqli_ or PDO... 
but i bet you're using mysql_connect wrong... is your server hostname really "root"? as in http://root/ ? i highly doubt it. see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php for the correct usage (or better yet, http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers ) 
..but something like

js:

```
var data={"foo":13,"bar":37};
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST","SendToDb.php");
var fd=new FormData();
fd.append("data",JSON.stringify(data));
xhr.send(fd);
```

SendToDb.php:

```
<?php

$data=json_decode($_POST['data'],true,1337);
//may want to validate data content
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'root', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
$pdos=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO `fpgis` (`foo`,`bar`) VALUES(?,?)");
$pdos->execute(array($data['foo'],$data['bar']));
unset($pdos);
```

....or if you really have to use mysql_ for some reason,

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password")or die('Could not connect:   '.mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("fpgis",$con);
        $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO     pointproperty(noPoint,latPoint,lngPoint,tipePoint)VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($data['noPoint'],$con)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data["latPoint"],$con)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data["lngPoint"],$con).",'".mysql_real_escape_string($data["tipePoint"],$con)."')";
        if(!mysql_query($sql,$con)){
             die('Error : '.mysql_error());
```

(if you don't use mysql_real_escape_string, your code will be unreliable when feeding it objects with properties or values containing special characters, and worse,  you're opening up your website for sql injection attacks, and you'll get hacked :p)